# Increasing number of semaphore handles

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization, locking

I have the following problem. In one of the libraries I noticed increasing number of events and semaphore handles. The only synchronization primitive I'm using is CriticalSection. What can be the cause of increasing handles that are not being closed?

OS: Windows Server 2003 R2
Compiler: Microsoft C++ 2003

Comment: Use Processexplorer or handles.exe (formerly sysinternals.com, currently technet) to diagnose handle usage. Perfmon can help in viewing the counts, WinDbg for the complicated cases

Comment: may be you are not deleting the critical section objects? Can you post some code?

Comment: Depends entirely on the definition and usage of `CriticalSection` if you are talking about windows API here then make sure you are calling `DeleteCriticalSection` when handles are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a [kernel object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485.aspx), a critical section internally uses other kernel objects such as event and/or semaphore (see e.g. [an article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164040.aspx); though it's quite old and the structures discussed there can be somewhat different in modern versions of Windows). So as others noted in comments, if you do not correctly release critical sections by calling [`DeleteCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682552.aspx), the number of handles in use will increase.